# How to set context to be default in kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

When I do :

```
$ kubectl config get-contexts


CURRENT   NAME                          CLUSTER                                                            AUTHINFO                                                           NAMESPACE
          kubernetes-admin@kubernetes   kubernetes                                                         kubernetes-admin
*         qa-1                        arn:aws:eks:xxxxxx150:cluster/ocean-qa   xxx:xxx:cluster/xxxx-RH36mmA4   xx-xx-tulw
```

I have multiple contexts defined in the config file. I would like to set 'kubernetes-admin@kubernetes' cluster as the default each time I use kubectl.

I can't find the command ..

Answer (score 0):

`kubectl config use-context kubernetes-admin@kubernetes` should be the command you are lookin for.

To check if it worked, use `kubectl config current-context`.

If in doubt, check its help with `kubectl config set-context --help`.